# 12.04 Graphics problem

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, drivers, nvidia, xorg

So I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit on a Dell XPS L502X with Nvidia GT540m. I'm having serious trouble with getting the drivers to work. Every solution i came across on the net didn't really work with my problem. Currently i have nvidia-current installed from ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates. Here is my lshw graphics output:

```
  *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:50 memory:f1400000-f17fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```

Before I downgraded to this version I've been using 12.10 64bit. The system failed to load pretty much, mostly running low graphics mode or flashing from purple to black on boot. This time this occured only once before i installed nvidia-current, but how do i know that the drivers are installed correctly because so far nothing indicates that. nvidia-detect returns "none" and after installing meta-utils my system info shows that i have Intel Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2. Furthermore, my xorg.conf isn't really helpful too:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
        Driver          "fbdev"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you intend to use both graphics chipsets simultaneously, try disabling the Intel graphics in your BIOS.  Ubuntu should then only detect and configure your nvidia card.